# ASP.NET 4 Returns a 500 error

Tags: iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET 4 page returns a 500 error. This is a single page with a single Response.Write command:

```
<% Response.Write("Hello World") %>
```

**IIS 7.5**

The website's permissions are:

```
SYSTEM
MACHINENAME\myusername
MACHINENAME\Administrators
MACHINENAME\Users
MACHINENAME\IIS_IUSRS
```

The Physical Path is:

```
C:\Users\myusername\Documents\mywebsite
```

The permissions on the physical path folder are:

```
SYSTEM
MACHINENAME\myusername
MACHINENAME\Administrators
MACHINENAME\Users
MACHINENAME\IIS_IUSRS
```

The application pool is set for **.NET Framework v4.0.30319** using managed pipeline mode: **Integrated**. Classic mode has been tried as well.

The web.config file contains the following lines:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

**IIS Authentication** is set to Anonymous Authentication - Enabled

**Physical Path** > Test Settings shows the following warning:

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is `NetworkService` or `LocalSystem`, verify that `<domain>\<computer_name>$` has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

I have tried everything that I have read to fix that, but nothing changes the outcome of a 500 error

Single log entry:

> 2012-03-22 19:24:16 172.16.35.115 GET /Default.aspx - 80 - 10.1.11.107 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:11.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/11.0 500 21 13 203

This is new for me, I never spent this much time getting a web page to load.

I also added the ISAPI filters for the 4.0 library, both 64bit and 32bit versions.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

All research leads me to think that there is a problem with the way that ASP.NET 4 is registered with IIS, and that the `aspnet_iisreg` utility should be run again. Unfortunately, I don't yet have permission to do that from the admin.

Comment: Could you share the actual aspx content?

Comment: @Joachim I have added that detail.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with IIS 8 on windows server 2012.
Enabling ASP.NET 4.5 in the server features resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error information displayed with the 500 error? I'd also check the Event Viewer on the server as errors are also logged there (in the Application log - from memory).

Comment: I am aware of all of the error reporting available to me. None of them are helpful in this instance.

Comment: Ok, that may be so - but you might want to explain that in your original question then.